# google chart query language throws null pointer exception

Tags: google-visualization

Here is my code that is used to get the graph information data table. I am clueless to find the cause of this issue.

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
function drawVisualization() {
    var sqlQuery = "sql?tq=select ProjectName, ExecutionDate, PassedWeekly, FailedWeekly &sqlQueryID=test_runs_week";
    var weeklyRunsQuery = new google.visualization.Query(sqlQuery);
    weeklyRunsQuery.send(handleWeeklyRunsResponse);
}
function handleWeeklyRunsResponse(queryWeeklyRunsResponse) {
    var responseDataTable = queryWeeklyRunsResponse.getDataTable();
    if (queryWeeklyRunsResponse.isError()) {
        alert(queryWeeklyRunsResponse.getDetailedMessage());
    }
    if (responseDataTable == null) {
        alert("Response is null");
        return;
    }
    if (responseDataTable.getNumberOfRows() < 0) {
        alert("Response has 0 rows");
    }
}
```

1. Observation 1: It is giving me the results of previously visited graph page.
2. Observation 2: If Tomcat server is restarted, it is giving me the "Error Message as internal error"
3. Observation 3: Navigate to other graph page and come back and execute this code,it will give you the previously visited page.

This is WEBINF\web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

    <description>
    </description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SqlDataSourceServlet</servlet-name>
        <description>SqlDataSourceServlet</description>
        <servlet-class>com.external.datasources.SqlDataSourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SqlDataSourceServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/htm/sql</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>depreport.htm</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: did you omit part of the url? -- `sqlQuery = "sql?tq=...` -- otherwise, doesn't look complete -- also `(responseDataTable.getNumberOfRows() < 0)` will never occur, use `Rows() === 0`

Comment: Thanks. It is my bad. My servlet and webapps folder does not the same.